# How can I serve the html, css, and js all while keeping the routes inside a module.export in a different file? Right now only html is served

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, web

I am a newbie to use express and as a result am bungling my way through making this web app.

I have my routes in a different file called route.js inside a module.export, and I manage all this inside app.js and I want to be able to serve a HTML page and keep it in the module. I've done so using sendFile but it doesn't serve the CSS and JS as well. What can I do to fix this?

app.js

```
//setup
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var index = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var flash    = require('connect-flash');
var passport = require('passport');
var session = require('express-session');
var path = require('path');

//db
var configDB = require('./config/database.js');
mongoose.connect(configDB.url);
require('./config/passport')(passport);

// view engine setup
//app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
//app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');



//routes
//app.use('/', index);
//app.use('/users', users);


// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));



//passport
app.use(session({secret: 'secret'}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(flash());

//routes
require('./app/routes.js')(app, passport);


// catch 404 and forward to error handler
/*app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});*/

// error handler
/*app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});*/

module.exports = app;

//launch
app.listen(port);
console.log('Website starting on port ' + port);
```

routes.js

```
module.exports = function(app,passport) {
...
    //--timesheet section---
    app.get('/timesheet', function(req, res) {
        var path = require('path');
        res.sendFile(path.resolve('public/timesheet.html'));
    });
...
}
```

Comment: Why not to simply use express.static to serve those files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use a [view engine](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html) and a [static](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html) directory.  You have some of the code already.

Your view engine using `.ejs`:

```
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
```

And you can define your static and specify a path prefix:

```
app.use('/assets', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

In your   `views` directory, put your htmls with `.ejs` extension, such as `timesheet.ejs`.  You can then create an `assets` directory for your css/js/image files and reference them in your `timesheet.ejs` using `/assets/style.css`.

Finally, in your route, you'll want to render the template:

```
res.render('timesheet')
```